# Find the next empty row within a range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there an easy way in App Script to find the next empty row within a range, for example I'd like the following:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
1|CODE RM1 RM2 RM3 NAME
2| 021  x       x  Pete
3| 531      x   x  Mike
4| 141             John
5| 155  x   x      Paul
```

return the next row blank row in the range B2:D
so it would return Row 4

other rows (like rows A & E in the above example) will have data so should be ignored.

I'm trying to write to the next blank row from another sheet (or tab) which has an input area for users to enter data and hit a button, the data will then add to the blank row on the target page (first row of `DATA!B2:D`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to do that with a spreadsheet formula:

`=+filter(row(B2:D), not(len(B2:B & C2:C & D2:D)))`

If you do not want the row number, but the value in column `A`, replace `row(B2:D)` with `A2:A`.

To do this in Apps Script, try this pattern:

```
const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Sheet1!B2:D');
const firstBlankRow = range.getValues().findIndex(row => !row.join('')) + 1;
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I need it to return in Google Apps Script, I'm trying to write to that row from another page when a user inputs values into a row. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Edited the answer to add Apps Script code.